# Does GNU make prepend a "./" to the path of included makefiles?

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make, absolute-path

Running GNU Make 4.4 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to `include` a generated makefile from another.  When the `include`d file is given as an absolute directory, I get the following error:

```
makefile:6: ./D:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Workspace/test/make/makefile-deps.mk: Invalid argument
make: *** No rule to make target './D:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Workspace/test/make/makefile-deps.mk'.  Stop.
```

Here is a makefile which re-creates the problem:

```
OUTPUT_DIR := $(abspath .)
DEPS_FILE := $(OUTPUT_DIR)/makefile-deps.mk
include $(DEPS_FILE)
CSRCS := a.c b.c c.c d.c
$(DEPS_FILE): $(CSRCS) $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    @echo MAKEDEPS
    @$(MAKEDEPS) --output-file $@ $(CSRCS)
show:
    @echo DEPS_FILE=$(DEPS_FILE)
```

If I comment out the include line, the `show` target shows that the directory is not prepended:

```
─▶ make show
DEPS_FILE=D:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Workspace/test/make/makefile-deps.mk
```

So it must be the `include` directive prepending the `./` to the path name, causing the failure.  Does any know a work-around for this?

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in `make`.  I submitted a bug report and it should be fixed in the next release. https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?63516